# In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I want to rewrite all http requests on my web server to be https requests, I started with the following:

```
server {
    listen      80;

    location / {
      rewrite     ^(.*)   https://mysite.com$1 permanent;
    }
...
```

One Problem is that this strips away any subdomain information (e.g., node1.mysite.com/folder), how could I rewrite the above to reroute everything to https and maintain the sub-domain?

Comment: Please consider moving the 'accepted answer' to http://serverfault.com/a/171238/90758.  That's the correct one.

Comment: Just use $server_name instead of hardcoded mysite.com

Answer (score 801, accepted):

## Correct way in new versions of nginx

Turn out my first answer to this question was correct at certain time, but it turned into another pitfall - to stay up to date please check [Taxing rewrite pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites)

I have been corrected by many SE users, so the credit goes to them, but more importantly, here is the correct code:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; 

       [....]
}
```

Comment: You would have to do this on a domain by domain basis however - no? What if you wanted to apply it to every domain on your server?

Comment: This seems all to work very well. But then, what will happen to the POST parameters? Body/Headers? Anybody got some inputs on this?

Comment: @nembleton Nothing will happen to the parameters. They will just be passed trough to your application.

Comment: @JM4: if you use $host$ in the rewrite instead of server_name and add default_server to the listen directive it will work for every domain on your server.

Comment: As of version 0.7.14, the standard way to enable SSL is through the listen parameter. Therefore it should be `listen 443 ssl;` instead of having `ssl on;`

Comment: @nembleton That's not true. POST body will be stripped off.

Comment: @Guy Are you sure nginx strips the POST body during a rewrite?

Comment: I had also to add the line keepalive_requests 0; in order to work ok in safari and chrome.

Comment: @JM4 @Klass van Schleven: you could also change `listen 80;` to `listen 80 default;` and then eliminate the `server_name` directive.

Comment: I had to do something similar with a vhost with both ssl and non ssl, the following rule worked for me: `rewrite ^!https https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent`

Comment: It's important to mention that the 301 is stored in your local cache without expiry date. Not very useful when config changes

Comment: @everyone Use a 307 redirect to preserve POST content.

Comment: So $server_name didn't work for me, but $host did. Not sure if this is a mistake or something wrong with my deployment. I see some of the other examples below recommending $host though.

Comment: @Trefex It's worse than that. Because this uses HSTS, your browser won't ever consult the HTTP server.

Comment: Note that you must use `$host` instead of `$server_name` if you're using subdomains.

Comment: Not working if you have a proxy like CloudFlare that handles https, while your server listens on port 80

Comment: @Catfish I'm using a subdomain and `$server_name` worked fine?

Comment: It'll work, but $server_name will always redirect to the first in the list, not the host you've connected to.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: This is in no way confirmed by the HTTP spec - 307 is no different than 301 in that regard (see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html section 10.3.8)

Comment: @ChrisWue see RFC 7231 S6.4.7: "Note: This status code is similar to 302 (Found), except that it       does not allow changing the request method from POST to GET."

Comment: @Catfish +1, you saved my day

Comment: Where is this file?

Comment: The problem with "return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;" is that $request_uri is never empty it contains at least a "/". so http ://example.com would redirect to https ://example.com/ (note the trailing slash). Services like Hardenize complain about this, is there a way to eliminate this slash?

Comment: Dear god! I had been reading all these articles that stated using `return 301 https://$host...` and it was not working. Changing it to `return 301 https://$server_name...` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: redirecting HTTP to HTTPS only worked for me on both Firefox and Chrome when i also added `listen [::]:80` and `listen [::]:443 ssl` to also support IPv6 instead of just IPv4, since if you only do `listen 80` and `listen 443 ssl` then it only supports IPv4 such that redirect would only work on Firefox but not Chrome

Answer (score 291):

**NOTE: The best way to do this was provided by https://serverfault.com/a/401632/3641 - but is repeated here:**

```
server {
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

In the simplest case your host will be fixed to be your service you want to send them to - this will do a 301 redirect to the browser and the browser URL will update accordingly.

**Below is the previous answer, which is inefficient due to regex, a simple 301 is great as shown by @kmindi**

I have been using nginx 0.8.39 and above, and used the following:

```
 server {
       listen 80;
       rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
 }
```

Sends a permanent redirect to the client.

Comment: I think it should be 80 - as this is listening for http and then telling the client to come back as https (443).

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Comment: This is the most taxing answer.

Comment: this is the easiest one, but the least secure - this way you allow your server to redirect a user to any page, without checking if it's even allowed to be used on your server. If your server serves mydomain.co, malicious users could still use your server to redirect users to other domains like mydomain.co, such as google.com.

Comment: Iscariot it is taxing - but only for port 80 traffic - if that helps ;)

Comment: @cab0lt I don't follow - it sends a permanent redirect to the client so the browsers url will change (see http://serverfault.com/a/401632/3641 for a less taxing version) - if you want to check what $host$ you could via various means in your config, if that helps.

Comment: @MichaelNeale: that's what I mean - combine a redirection with a wildcard always with a list of allowed locations

Comment: got it, thanks. Have clarified things (hopefully!) - this Q&A keeps popping up over and over (which is good to see).

Comment: @cab0lt there is no security issue here.  Serving a redirect doesn't present a security risk.  If there's access control requirements, those should be checked at the point where the browser requests the new URL.  The browser won't gain access simply on the basis of the redirect, nor do they need the redirect to request the new URL.

Comment: Does this answer imply settings for port 443 to be already present in the nginx configuration file?

Comment: @Waseem yes, you should already have the other https blocks defined. This block should come above the others.

Comment: `$host` >>> `$server_name` !!!!

Comment: For some reason this one works whereas the top solution doesn't

Answer (score 132):

I think the best and only way should be using a **[HTTP 301 Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2)** redirect like this:

```
server {
    listen         [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The **HTTP 301 Moved Permanently** redirect is also the most efficient because there is no regex to be evaluated, according to already mentioned [pitfails](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites).

---

The new [**HTTP 308  Moved Permanently**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538) preserves the Request method and is [supported by major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308). For example, using `308` prevents browsers from changing the request method from `POST` to `GET` for the redirect request.

---

If you want to **preserve the hostname and subdomain** this is the way.

This **does still work if you have no DNS**, as I am also using it locally.
I am requesting for example with `http://192.168.0.100/index.php` and will get redirected to exactly `https://192.168.0.100/index.php`.

I use `listen [::]:80` on my host because i have `bindv6only` set to `false`, so it also binds to ipv4 socket. change it to `listen 80` if you don't want IPv6 or want to bind elsewhere.

The solution from Saif Bechan uses the `server_name` which in my case is localhost but that is not reachable over a network.

The solution from Michael Neale is good, but according to the pitfails, there is a better solution with redirect 301 ;)

Comment: Nice you try to quote it, but 301 does not work on HTTPS.

Comment: what does not work? the stated server section is for non-encrypted http (without s) traffic to be permanently redirected to encrypted server (that section that listens on 443 (https) is not listed)

Comment: I checked this works great with https and everything - @kmindi I updated my answer with reference to yours - as I think it is the right way and this keeps popping up! Nice work.

Comment: When using a domain (non-ip) request, does not work unless I change '[::]:80' to '80'.

Comment: that could be the expected behaviour: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/345. I updated the answer to describe the listen option.

Comment: Why would you use 301 or 308, when there is 307 ? This is actually very bad advice in a "let's try if it works" thread like this one here. Always use Temporary redirects until you're absolutely certain it all does what you want it to. Just leave it for a few days and check the logs for strange behavior. You can always change it to 308, or 301 later, no need to rush that change either.

Comment: Can similar behaviour be used for redirecting host names? I.e. redirect www hosts to non-www (full question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1066676/nginx-how-do-i-force-all-server-domains-and-server-blocks-to-use-non-www-redir)

Answer (score 26):

Within the server block you can also do the following:

```
# Force HTTPS connection. This rules is domain agnostic
if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: This configuration caused my server to produce a redirect loop

Comment: Maybe cause there's another redirect in place or https is not enable in your site/app

Comment: None of the others seemed to work except this one. Using nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: upvoted for https://$host$uri

Comment: This is the way to go if you are behind a loadbalancer !

Comment: This works, In a scenario where clients create their own subdomain everytime

Answer (score 19):

The above didn't work for with with new subdomains being created all the time.
e.g. AAA.example.com BBB.example.com for about 30 subdomains.

Finally got a config working with the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
  listen  443;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myssl.key;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
# ...
# rest of config here
# ...
}
```

Comment: thank you! nginx would either return `301 https://*/` or cancel the request prematurely in the other answers here. `server_name _;` with `$host` was the answer that did the trick. +1

Comment: This one is optimal! However, I recommend for some to replace `_` with the actual domain, e.g. `.domain.com` I had two servers, and nginx was accidentally directing one of my servers to the default server.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.. I have tried many of the solutions but didnt worked out. This solutions is awesome and it worked for me.  server_name _; what is this meant for.. I didnt understand. Please explain me this.

Answer (score 12):

I posted a comment on the correct answer a long, long time ago with a very important correction, but I feel it is necessary to highlight this correction in its own answer. **None of the previous answers are safe to use if at any point you had unsecure HTTP set up and expect user content, have forms, host an API, or have configured any website, tool, application, or utility to speak to your site.**

The problem occurs when a `POST` request is made to your server. If the server response with a plain `301`/`302` redirect **the POST content will be lost.** What happens is that the browser/client will upgrade the request to SSL but *downgrade* the `POST` to a `GET` request. The `POST` parameters will be lost and incorrect request will be made to your server.

The solution is simple. You need to use a `HTTP 1.1 307` redirect. This is detailed in RFC 7231 S6.4.7:

```
  Note: This status code is similar to 302 (Found), except that it
  does not allow changing the request method from POST to GET.  This
  specification defines no equivalent counterpart for 301 (Moved
  Permanently) ([RFC7238], however, defines the status code 308
  (Permanent Redirect) for this purpose).
```

The solution, adapted from the accepted solution, is to use `307` in your redirect code:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         307 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 

       [....]
}
```

Comment: Note that 308 is preferable to 307 if you want to signify a **permanent redirect** (equivalent to 301) — see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138726/7734384).

Answer (score 5):

I am running ngnix behind an AWS ELB.  The ELB is talking to ngnix over http.  Since the ELB has no way to send out redirects to clients, I check for the X-Forwarded-Proto header and redirect:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    return 301 "https://www.exampl.com";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;

server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;

# global HTTP handler
if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
}

# global non-WWW HTTPS handler
if ($http_host = domain.tld){
        return 303 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
}
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777526/6076984

Comment: Updated version, w/o IF: https://paste.debian.net/plain/899679

Answer (score 4):

If you `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` as the default response on port 80, then your server may sooner or later get on a list of open proxies[1] and start being abused to send traffic elsewhere on the Internet. If your logs fill up with messages like this one, then you know it's happened to you:

```
42.232.104.114 - - [25/Mar/2018:04:50:49 +0000] "GET http://www.ioffer.com/i/new-fashion-fine-gold-bracelet-versaec-bracelet-641175733 HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "http://www.ioffer.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Hotbar 4.1.8.0; RogueCleaner; Alexa Toolbar)"
```

The problem is that `$host` will echo back whatever the browser sends in the `Host` header or even the hostname from HTTP's opening line, like this one:

```
GET http://www.ioffer.com/i/new-fashion-fine-gold-bracelet-versaec-bracelet-641175733 HTTP/1.1
```

Because of that problem, some other answers here recommend using `$server_name` instead of `$host`. `$server_name` always evaluates to what *you* put in the `server_name` declaration. But if you have multiple subdomains there or use a wildcard, that won't work, because `$server_name` only uses the *first* entry after the `server_name` declaration, and more importantly will just echo back a wildcard (not expand it).

So how to support multiple domains while maintaining security? On my own systems I've dealt with this dilemma by *first* listing a `default_server` block that doesn't use `$host`, and then listing a wildcard block that does:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

(You could also list more than one domain in the second block.)

With that combination, unmatched domains will get redirected somewhere hardcoded (always `example.com`), and domains that match your own will go to the right place. Your server won't be useful as an open proxy, so you won't be attracting trouble.

If you are feeling ornery, I suppose you could also make the `default_server` block match *none* of your legitimate domains and serve something offensive. . . .

[1] Technically "proxy" is the wrong word, because your server isn't going out and fulfilling requests for the clients, just sending a redirect, but I'm not sure what the right word would be. I'm also not sure what the goal is, but it fills up your logs with noise and consumes your CPU and bandwidth, so you might as well put a stop to it.

Comment: Do you have any precedent about such "open proxy" because of code `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` ? I like the idea to create one universal block to redirect any my HTTP website to the same but HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like nobody really got it 100% right. To have port 80 requests go to their 443 equivalents for an entire webserver, **you need to use the *listen* directive, not the server_name directive to specify the catch-all** name. See also https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    listen [::]:80 default;
      return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

- $host catches subdomain names.
- 307 and 308 include both POST and GET request URIs.
- 307 is Temporary, change to the Permanent 308 after thorough testing:

And make sure you check what's already in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ because more often than not I had issues where the default.conf returned some existing vhost. My order of working with nginx issues is always starting by moving out the default file, putting it back commenting out line by line to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^!https https://$host$request_uri permanent;
```