# http -> https redirection with websockets

Tags: nginx, iptables, http, redirect, https

I have a Node.js app which is heavily reliant on websockets. I want to redirect anyone trying to access it via http (80) to https (443). I would use nginx however it does not play well with websockets. No other service needs to run on the server.

What is the best way to do this redirect?

Comment: You can do this as described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this but a simple one would be for Nginx to listen only on port 80 (HTTP) and redirect all traffic to 443 (where nodejs is listneing) before any web socket connections are initiated.

Comment: how can I do it?