# How to serve same content to https and http with nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

Typically my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    <some long config>
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  example.com;

    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     qwe.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key qwe.key;

    <the same long config>
}
```

How to forward all https requests to http server directive (not send redirect to client but forward within nginx) so that I will not need to write the same config twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;

    <some long config>
}
```

Comment: Whilst this will serve the same stuff to both `http` and `https`, does it actually redirect the client from `https` over to `http`?

Comment: @JohnMee the point is *not* to redirect user but to serve same content. This config does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have two server directives...

- One that listens on port 80 and does a rewrite
- And another that listens on port 443 and is your main config

Of course you can do this the other way around (https redirect to http) it makes no difference.

[In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom)

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
       listen         443;
       server_name    my.domain.com;

       ssl            on;

       [....]
}
```

Comment: Looks like rewrite directive will send 301 redirect to user. I don't want to send any redirects to user.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read that bit. Typically I'm used to doing redirections as it's best for SEO purposes to have only one site. If you respond with 200's on multiple sites (ie http & https) this could be seen as duplicate content. Make sure you're aware of the implications.