# nginx https redirect not working

Tags: nginx

My config is as follows:

```
    server {
      listen *:80;
      server_name example.com;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

  server {
      listen *:443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate /directory/of/cert/cert.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /directory/of/cert/cert.pem;
      proxy_ssl_ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL;
      proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

      location / {
      proxy_pass http://localip:8080;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        }
    }
```

However, when I curl -v to example.com, I get a time-out

```
curl -v http://host.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://host.example.com/
*   Trying <public_ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to <public_ip> port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to host.example.com port 80: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.example.com port 80: Timed out
```

I've done some Googling and found this link: [nginx redirect http to https not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/680580/nginx-redirect-http-to-https-not-working)

[christofferp](https://serverfault.com/users/317431/christofferp) suggested that it could be the /sites-enabled/default config taking precedence and causing the problem, I've removed mine, but still having trouble.

I have tried a number of different config changes, but cannot seem to get it working.

Any ideas? Could it be something in my config that's wrong?

Comment: a timeout usually points toward a firewall problem. Apart from that, you've set `example.com` in your server config, but you try to connect to `host.example.com`.

Comment: Damnit! It was the firewall, thanks Gerald. As I read your comment I realised I never opened HTTP. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Gerald Schneider](https://serverfault.com/users/38644/gerald-schneider), I forgot to open HTTP on the firewall! Solved my problem.