# browser returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE if https:// is not included with TDL

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

When a device tries to reach 'GraphWhy.org' they receive the following error 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.

Connections only occur if 'https://graphwhy.org' is entered

My Nginx file follows. I have tried most of the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom) .

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    graphwhy.org;
       return         301 https://graphwhy.org$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name graphwhy.org;
        ....
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name chat.graphwhy.org;
        ....
}
```

Thank you in advance. Sorry if you think the question is poorly asked. I'm happy to doctor the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your server isn't listening on port 80, or that port is being blocked by your firewall.