# Force redirect to https on specific port on nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have website on port 8080 and I want to force https on it.
ex.
If I type http://mywebsite.com:8080, it should redirect to https://mywebsite.com:8080

How can I do this in nginx conf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx will emit [non-standard error code](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors) `497` which could be processed with [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive. So this would work:

```
server {
    listen 8080 ssl;

    error_page 497 @force_https;

    location @force_https {
        return 301 'https://$host:$server_port$request_uri';
    }
}
```

Works:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080/test/me
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: https://localhost:8080/test/me
```

Comment: thx but it does not seem to work :( .. it is not redirecting for me

Comment: @k1ler how did you check? Show your config.

Comment: ah I think it is redirecting... stupid chrome I can't see properly when it is http or https.. thx man!

Comment: Btw, browser will cache 301 redirect so next time it will replace http with https without hitting server.

Comment: thx man! 
I am new to nginx

"server {
    listen 8080 ssl;"

what does the ssl next to the 8080 mean?