# Removing folder directories from a URL using Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am using YetiShare PHP Script

I want to change this

> /plugins/rewards/site/rewards.php

to

> /rewards.php or /rewards

I have searched and tried all possible solutions on here and elsewhere to no result, I am getting 404 errors with most. I really hope someone can help me here, I will appreciate it so very much!

Comment: Please share the output of `nginx -T` of a configuration that is failing.

Comment: needs a lot more informations, nginx configuration as example missing - you want to rewrite your request.
moreover, its a kind of Duplicate off https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom